# BeutifulSoup image scraping returns too few pictures

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is my first script for scraping images from the web put together from a few examples from the web. I used `nbr_of_images = 50` and got 20 dancer and 20 chair images. So I thought that by using `nbr_of_images = 100` I'd get about 50 of both. But the script still gets me 20 dancer images and 20 chair images. I can't see why. Could someone help me out?

```py
# A script for downloading images from URLs.
import sys 
import requests 
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def is_valid(url):
    """is_valid checks whether input URL is valid.
    Parameters
    ----------
    url : str
        The URL to be validated.
    Returns
    -------
    valid : Bool
        a Boolean value describing if the input URL is valid or not.
    """
    
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    valid = bool(parsed.netloc) and bool(parsed.scheme)
    return valid

def get_n_images(url, folder, nbr_of_images, dancer):
    """get_n_images extracts image URLs from the imput URL and downloads
    the image URL contents to a given folder.
    Parameters
    ----------
    url : str
        The URL from which the image URLs are extracted.
    folder : str
        Path for the image download folder.
    nbr_of_images : int
        The number of image URLs to be extracted.
    dancer : Bool
        A Boolean for checking if the images are dancer images or not.
    """
    
    if is_valid(url):
        soup = bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    else:
        print('Invalid URL. Aborting.')
        sys.exit(1)
    n_images = soup.find_all('img', limit=nbr_of_images)
    for i, image in enumerate(n_images):
        # Get the image url.
        try:
            image_link = image['data-srcset']
        except:
            try:
                image_link = image['data-src']
            except:
                try:
                    image_link = image['data-fallback-src']
                except:
                    try:
                        image_link = image['src']
                    except:
                        pass
        # Get the content of the image url.
        dancers = f'{folder}/dancer{i+1}.jpg'
        non_dancers = f'{folder}/image{i+1}.jpg'
        try:
            image = requests.get(image_link).content
            try:
                image = str(image, 'utf-8')
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                if dancer:
                    with open(dancers, 'wb') as pic:
                        pic.write(image)
                else:
                    with open(non_dancers, 'wb') as pic:
                        pic.write(image)                    
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nbr_of_images = 100
    url_dancers = 'https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enFI1058FI1058&q=dancer+from+above&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTtbm2u6SAAxWaS_EDHYrCC1AQ0pQJegQICBAB&biw=1536&bih=707&dpr=1.25'
    url_chairs = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=chair+from+above&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwihr47Uu6SAAxUCIxAIHcHUBAUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=chair+from+above&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQBxAeMggIABAFEAcQHjIICAAQBRAHEB4yBggAEAUQHjoHCAAQigUQQ1C0F1jhG2DEImgAcAB4AIABPYgByAKSAQE2mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=KOy8ZKH7OILGwPAPwamTKA&bih=707&biw=1536&rlz=1C1GCEA_enFI1058FI1058'
    get_n_images(url_dancers, 'training_images', nbr_of_images, True)
    get_n_images(url_chairs, 'training_images', nbr_of_images, False)
```

Comment: It might be the case that the other images are lazy loaded, which means a real user needs to scroll the page to see those pictures, so as the scrapper. You need to consider scrolling the page in the script itself

Comment: Weird, I opened one of the pages in my browser and didn't scroll, I pressed F12 and typed `$x('//img')` in the console, 114 elements were found.

Comment: The images were indeed lazy loaded, and I have found that Google uses XHR, I have found the following url: `https://www.google.com/_/VisualFrontendUi/data/batchexecute`, and the information about the rest of the images is in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The quality of your code isn't very good. But I won't review it here. That being said, I have investigated the issue, and found the cause of the problem.

The images were indeed lazy loaded, and they are only loaded when the user scrolls the page to them. When new images are about to be scrolled into view an XHR request to this file `https://www.google.com/_/VisualFrontendUi/data/batchexecute` was initiated, the method was post.

The information about the images, more specifically the addresses of the images were contained in the response.

Unfortunately my JavaScript isn't good at all, and I am completely unable to reverse engineer the parameters of the request. And the response is not valid json.

But I did manage to recreate one of the requests using parameters found in devtools. I analyzed the response and got the urls using regex, and I want to post a partial answer here as a starting point for future full answers.

The request is below, it may fail tomorrow.

```
res = requests.post("https://www.google.com/_/VisualFrontendUi/data/batchexecute?rpcids=HoAMBc&source-path=%2Fsearch&f.sid=508111283055761867&bl=boq_visualfrontendserver_20230719.00_p6&hl=en&authuser=0&soc-app=162&soc-platform=1&soc-device=1&_reqid=281340&rt=c", 
headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "X-Same-Domain": "1",
    "x-goog-ext-190139975-jspb": "[\"ZZ\",\"ZZ\",\"Kg7XhekhgQAJQBiW6tLa/A==\"]",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    "referrer": "https://www.google.com/"
},
data = "f.req=%5B%5B%5B%22HoAMBc%22%2C%22%5Bnull%2Cnull%2C%5B1%2Cnull%2C457%2C1%2C1536%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C353%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5C%22dancer%20from%20above%5C%22%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5Bnull%2C%5C%22CAE%3D%5C%22%2C%5C%22GGggAA%3D%3D%5C%22%5D%5D%22%2Cnull%2C%22generic%22%5D%5D%5D&at=AAuQa1rq53lAnEq5S6CZ3PKz1Szw%3A1690122929663&",
)
```

It response uses mangled JSON syntax, but I did manage to find the urls by
using regex.

```
url_regex = re.compile(r'https?://([-\w()@:%\+.~#?&//=\\]+\.?)+')
urls = url_regex.findall(res.content.decode('utf8'))
```

The links all ended with a literal backwards slash (in Python it is `'\\'`), so we need to ignore it by slicing.

And there are lots of `encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images` urls, they are like the following:

```
'encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcTorpV_AWla-B_Ii5p5bslG1tX5V7yGy0GKNQ\\\\u0026usqp\\\\u003dCAU\\'
```

We can decode it by first removing the last slash as mentioned above, then we replace 2 backwards slashes with one, then add two literal quotes to the start and end of the string, then use `eval` on it, like so:

```
url = 'encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcSGTFRp_kOm1ELjlV58Bxqr56ioJ1EMuTnrOw\\\\u0026usqp\\\\u003dCAU\\'

url = 'https://' + eval('"' + url[:-1].replace('\\\\', '\\') + '"')
```

Then we can just download the image normally.

Also by using `pathlib.Path` you don't need to use `with open` syntax.

Code:

```
import random
import re
import requests
from pathlib import Path

res = requests.post("https://www.google.com/_/VisualFrontendUi/data/batchexecute?rpcids=HoAMBc&source-path=%2Fsearch&f.sid=508111283055761867&bl=boq_visualfrontendserver_20230719.00_p6&hl=en&authuser=0&soc-app=162&soc-platform=1&soc-device=1&_reqid=281340&rt=c", 
headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "X-Same-Domain": "1",
    "x-goog-ext-190139975-jspb": "[\"ZZ\",\"ZZ\",\"Kg7XhekhgQAJQBiW6tLa/A==\"]",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    "referrer": "https://www.google.com/"
},
data = "f.req=%5B%5B%5B%22HoAMBc%22%2C%22%5Bnull%2Cnull%2C%5B1%2Cnull%2C457%2C1%2C1536%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C353%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5C%22dancer%20from%20above%5C%22%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5Bnull%2C%5C%22CAE%3D%5C%22%2C%5C%22GGggAA%3D%3D%5C%22%5D%5D%22%2Cnull%2C%22generic%22%5D%5D%5D&at=AAuQa1rq53lAnEq5S6CZ3PKz1Szw%3A1690122929663&",
)
url_regex = re.compile(r'https?://([-\w()@:%\+.~#?&//=\\]+\.?)+')

urls = url_regex.findall(res.content.decode('utf8'))

for url in urls:
    url = url[:-1]
    is_image = False
    if url.startswith('encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images'):
        is_image = True
        url = 'https://' + eval('"' + url.replace('\\\\', '\\') + '"')
    elif url.endswith(('.jpg', '.gif', '.png')):
        is_image = True
        url = f'https://{url}'
    if is_image:
        Path(f'D:/image_test/{random.randbytes(8).hex()}.jpg').write_bytes(requests.get(url).content)
```

I am unable to go further, but it might give others who are facing the same problem a head start.